# Use regex in python flavor to match a (or all) bash's tilde-prefix(es) from a string?

Tags: python, regex, bash

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html about tilde expansion in bash:

> If a word begins with an **unquoted** tilde character (‘~’), all of the characters up to the first **unquoted** slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.

How can one use regex in python flavor to match a (or all) tilde-prefix(es) from a string?

If ignoring the two "unquoted" requirements, my regex is `(~[.*])/` and `\1` is a matched tilde-prefix.

But I don't know how to represent "unquoted" requirements.

Comment: Python has standard-library functions for expanding these for you; see `os.path.expanduser()`. Why do it yourself?

Comment: ...as for "unquoted", native Python strings don't have syntactical quotes within their data, so they don't have (as bash does) character-by-character metadata on whether and how any given character was quoted. So the scenario isn't something that can possibly happen in a Python string, unless you're trying to build a parser for shell syntax. And if you're doing the latter, a regex is simply the wrong tool for the job -- POSIX sh isn't a regular language (in the formal meaning of the term).

Comment: ...which is to say: You absolutely can ignore the "unquoted" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
~[^\\/\s]*(?:\\.[^\\/\s]*)*
```

`[^\\/\s]*` : zero or more characters that are not a slash, a backslash or a white character.

`(?:\\.[^\\/\s]*)*` : zero or more repeats of a non capturing group that starts with an escaped (quoted) character and the same than before.

Comment: The requirement isn't that the content *after* the tilde be escaped or quoted (or that such content *not* be quoted), but that the tilde itself not be escaped or quoted. But see my commentary on TLJ's answer and the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
(~[^/]*)
```

This matches the tilde prefix plus all non-slash characters which follow.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

`[^'"](~[^/]*)` Group anything after ~ that's not leading by single or double quote to /

Comment: Tilde expansion only takes place at the start of a shell word. Unless the OP is doing something unreasonable, they should be representing a filename as a single Python string, so it should only be necessary to recognize the tilde at the beginning of the string.

Comment: (Whether a given character will be parsed as "unquoted" by a shell isn't something a regex is a good fit to handle. Consider, for instance, `"hello"~` -- the tilde is unquoted, though it's also not at the beginning of the word; that's also the case for `hello\ ~world` -- the tilde is both unquoted, and part of a prior word, since the backslash prevents the whitespace from having semantic meaning).

Comment: ...and then you've got cases where quote characters themselves are quoted or escaped and thus lose semantic meaning. And backticks, which change how escape characters themselves are parsed. It's a huge mess, and trying to solve it with regexes is bringing a stick to a gunfight.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough